# Iterate JSON file and update values using shell script without JQ

Tags: shell, fastlane

In shell script, I want to read the content from file `swiftlint.json`.

Iterate the array of dictionary with key `issues`. Read the value for key `filePath` and add `/private` in the beginning.

Here is the content of file

```json
{
    "issues": [{
        "engineId": "SwiftLint",
        "primaryLocation": {
            "filePath": "\/RegistrationUtilities.swift",
            "message": "Function should have complexity 15 or less: currently complexity equals 18",
            "textRange": {
                "startLine": 29
            }
        },
        "ruleId": "cyclomatic_complexity",
        "severity": "MINOR",
        "type": "CODE_SMELL"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `jq`? Or alternately, why can't you use a language other than shell for parsing the JSON?

Comment: The count of JSON processors listed at [json.org](https://www.JSON.org/json-en.html) is currently at one hundred and seventy (170).